# MKMapView NSInvalidArgumentException: Invalid Region

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, mkmapview

I'm getting the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Region <center:+37.32462723, -122.02352434 span:+0.00000260, -0.00055282>'

This is my code:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

var mapOverlay: MKTileOverlay!
let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
var databaseHandle: UInt!
var runName: String!
var seconds = 0.0
var distance = 0.0
var avgPace = 0.0
var minLat = 0.0
var minLng = 0.0
var maxLat = 0.0
var maxLng = 0.0
var coordinate: MKCoordinateRegion!



@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var distanceLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var paceLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureView()
}

func configureView() {

    distanceLabel.text = ("Distance: " + String(round(distance)) + " metres")
    timeLabel.text = ("You ran this route in " + String(round(seconds)) + " seconds")

    databaseHandle = databaseRef.child("RunList").child(runName).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let dataDict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
        let startLatData = dataDict?["startLat"]

    })

    databaseHandle = databaseRef.child("RunList").child(runName).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let runData = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
        self.minLat = (runData?["startLat"] as? Double)!
        self.minLng = (runData?["startLong"] as? Double)!
        self.maxLat = (runData?["endLat"] as? Double)!
        self.maxLng = (runData?["endLong"] as? Double)!

        self.mapView.region = self.mapRegion()
        print(self.minLat)
        print(self.maxLng)

    })


}


func mapRegion() -> MKCoordinateRegion {


    return MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (self.minLat + self.maxLat)/2,
                                       longitude: (self.minLng + self.maxLng)/2),
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: (self.maxLat - self.minLat)*1.1,
                               longitudeDelta: (self.maxLng - self.minLng)*1.1))


}

}
```

I believe my lat and long values are within the requirements (-90, 90) and (-180,190) respectively. Why is my program crashing when I am trying to set the map region?

Comment: I think it is an issue with my MKCoordinateSpan Delta values..

Comment: I think I have solved my issue by adding abs() before setting the delta values for latitude and longitude, am going to test it around before confirming a solution.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?